# SQL server buffer cache vs memory-optimized tables

Tags: sql-server, performance

SQL Server 2014 introduced "memory-optimized tables", whose documentation states that "The primary storage for memory-optimized tables is the main memory. Rows in the table are read from and written to memory. A second copy of the table data is maintained on disk, but only for durability purposes."

This seems to imply a significant performance gain, but doesn't SQL Server have an in-memory buffer cache anyway?  If frequent queries are going to use the in-memory buffer cache, why is having a in-memory table providing a significant performance gain?

Comment: In-memory tables **may** provide a performance gain but it depends on the workload (generally high-end OLTP).  Data must be memory resident before usage, including disk-based tables. In-memory table structures are optimized for memory resident access without the compromises needed for disk-based tables plus additional options like hash indexes for more efficient point lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "memory-optimized tables" live in memory at all times, ready to be read from the memory at all times. The copy on the disk is like a backup copy just in case if the memory had any issues so it can be reloaded from disk into memory again.

The Buffer cache is used to load data pages from disk into memory, only when there is a request to read those pages and they stay in the memory until the pages are required by other process doing similar request. If the data in memory is no longer required and there is a need to load other pages into memory, those pages already loaded in the memory will get flushed out of memory, until there is a request to read those pages again.

Can you see the difference now? "memory-optimized tables" always live in memory whether someone makes a request to read those pages or not. A standard persisted table will only be cached in memory when someone makes a request for those pages, and will be flushed out if those in memory pages are not being used and there is a need to load more pages in memory.

Comment: Isn't SQL Server smarter than that?  I thought that it prioritized holding data in memory for frequently used queries.

Comment: @Jez yes SQL Server does a pretty good job of caching data and flushing it out when a certain threshold is hit, but it is a completely separate topic, I feel it will be out of scope to answer a fairly simple question the PO has asked. The difference between "memory-optimized tables"  and Standard SQL Server tables. I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: I am the OP, lol.

Comment: lol @Jez sorry didnt realise it :D, but I hope my answer has at least answered your original question :)